# SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService with ChromeDriver and SeleniumGrid through Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

Hi anyone know what is going on or how I can debug the error as following. the step I did is using setup hub command and register node to hub. after the command register node. I can see the log as

```
The node is registered to the hub and ready to use
```

However when I run the test script I have error print up as:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService
```

Binary versions:

- selenium standalone version: 3.14.0
- selenium remote driver version: selenium==3.14.1
- python version: 3.6.4

Script:

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
                          desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.CHROME)
```

Setup hub:

```
#java -jar /Users/admin/selenium-server-standalone-3.14.0.jar -host localhost -role hub
```

Register node:

```
#java -jar /Users/admin/selenium-server-standalone-3.14.0.jar -role node
```

Error:

```
E       selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService
E       Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:13:22.693Z'
E       Driver info: driver.version: unknown
E       Stacktrace:
E           at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ServicedSession$Factory.lambda$get$0 (ServicedSession.java:134)
E           at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ServicedSession$Factory.apply (ServicedSession.java:151)
E           at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ActiveSessionFactory.lambda$apply$12 (ActiveSessionFactory.java:177)
E           at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept (ReferencePipeline.java:193)
...
E           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call (Executors.java:511)
E           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:266)
E           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
E           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
E           at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:745)

../lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py:242: SessionNotCreatedException
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to initiate/spawn a new **ChromeDriverService**.

There are a couple of issues in the *commands* and *incompatibility* between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- Your *JDK version* is **1.8.0_91** which is pretty **ancient**.
- Upgrade *JDK* to  recent levels [**JDK 8u181**](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
- To register a *Selenium Grid Hub* you need to use the following command:

  ```
  >java -jar /Users/admin/selenium-server-standalone-3.14.0.jar -role hub
  ```
- To register a *Selenium Grid Node* for *ChromeDriver* and *Chrome* you need to pass the absolute path of the *ChromeDriver* along with the *Key* and *Value* of the **Registration URI** as follows:

  ```
  >java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/path/to/chromedriver.exe -jar /Users/admin/selenium-server-standalone-3.14.0.jar -role node -hub http://<IP_GRID_HUB>:4444/grid/register
  ```
- You code block looks good to me.

Comment: thank you. but i do not want to use my local chromedriver. I just want to use selenium remote webdriver any reason I need to add -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver wehn register node?

Comment: @A.Lee What do you mean by _...local chromedriver..._? You need to have the _chromedriver_ to register the _Node_ to the _Hub_ as a mandatory measure. `-Dwebdriver.chrome.driver` is a required argument to specify the _chromedriver_ location in _Grid_ configuration. Let me know if you have any other queries.

Comment: thank you..i guess i always put chromedriver under PATH before and use alias without noticing that..but for some reason, it is all broken. after update JDK for 1.11 and using selenium standalone3.14.1 chromedriver 2.42 version. it works

Answer (score 0):

Post upgrading the jdk/java version and Seleniumserverstandalone3.5.3 worked for me.

Comment: Can you elaborate?